# C++ CLR Managed DLL cannot use vector members

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr, managed

I have the following code inside my class:

```
#include <cliext/vector>


vector<String ^> temp;

void Database::EditInfo()
{
 StreamReader ^MyInFile= gcnew StreamReader("Database.txt");
  while (!MyInFile->EndOfStream)
    {
        temp.push_back(MyInFile->ReadLine());
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < temp.size; i++){ //statements }
}
```

I get an error [image]

I dont understand why I cannot use the vector members though it shows no error when I dont build it

EDIT: I forgot the () beside the size. The only problem now is the error "Cannot use this indirection on type 'System::String^' due to the push_back

Answer (score 0):

System::String is a managed type, std::vector is not. They don't play well together. You should either use std::string with your vector or a `System::Collections::Generic::List<>` for your managed types.

```
std::vector<std::string> plain;
```

OR

```
System::Collections::Generic::List<System::String^>^ managed;
```

In general, why are you using C++/CLI at all? It will hurt you multiple times along your way. C++/CLI combines the slow performance of .NET and the cryptic syntax of C++. If you don't see why you would want to do this, save yourself a year of pain and chose either C# or plain C++ whatever fits your need. C++/CLI is a specialized language for those who need to combine those two because they have legacy code to wrap or need to interface with something unmamanged.

Comment: Hi, I am using C++/CLI for a project requirement. I use vector that stores lines within a text file. Since it has member 'Contains', its easy for me to search for a word from a line.  Is there anything that you could suggest that is the same with this?

Comment: @BrianSanchez Yes. Either do it in plain C++ with std::ifstream and std::string or do it managed with `array<String^>^ lines = System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(path);` but please pick one, mixing them will only make you wish you never started programming in the first place. Make sure you did not misunderstand your project requirement. C++/CLI only makes sense in a very, very small subset of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `vector<string> temp` for your text data, "fstream" for loading files and "find_if" with string comparing mechanisms from std for searching in vector.

Using C++ standart libraries, while you programming on C++ - have to be good solution.